Cannot connect to MySql via SSH Tunnel
I have a MySQL database server with bind-address set to 10.x.y.z (IMPORTANT: not listening on localhost etc)
The web nodes can connect and use MySQL no problem.
Now I'm trying to access MySQL from my local machine.
First set up a tunnel with:
ssh -N -L 3306:10.x.y.z:3306 user@dbserver

Now try mysql:
mysql -h 10.x.y.z -u dbuser -p

It hangs for a long time and finally returns with "Can't connect to MySQL server on '10.x.y.z:3306' (110)".
If I SSH into the server, I can connect to mysql just fine. Either with
mysql -u dbuser -p

or with
mysql -h 10.x.y.z -u dbuser -p

I have also confirmed that /etc/ssh/sshd_config has
AllowTcpForwarding set to yes.
What am I doing wrong with the tunnel part?

No - unfortunately not - same result

mysqld is not listening to localhost, tunneling works by making the connection from the ssh server available from the ssh client. User68186 rightfully explained to use 127.0.0.1 on the client, to use the ssh tunnel, but you stated mysqld is not listening to localhost on the server side.

I tried again and magically it worked this time. Not sure what was going on before because I know I tried that multiple times with no success. Anyway, thanks user68186 and sleepyhead

Use the localhost as destination
The ssh tunnel with the -L option sets up the localhost as the address when the local IP address is omitted. See this how to for details
First set up a tunnel with:
ssh -N -L 3306:10.x.y.z:3306 user@dbserver

Launch mysql:
mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -u dbuser -p

Now it should work.
